# Chrome's map to file system resource not working after update

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I can add a folder to the workspace (which doesn't seem to do anything, as far as I can tell), but the "map to file system resource" option seems to have been removed, and I can no longer live-edit css files.

Is this a bug, or has the process for mapping css files been changed?

This talk (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes) says that the new version uses "magic" to map remote files to local ones, but I can't seem to get it to work at all.

For reference, I'm trying to map a reddit css file to one on my own computer. It worked fine on a previous version of Chrome (basically I add the folder, and map the css file inside it, which has been renamed to have the same name as the remote one) but not on the new one (Chrome 63)

Answer (score 14):

I've just fiddled around with a problem, where only some files got mapped to my local workspace.

[image]

Turned out that Google Chrome also checks and compares the **last modified date** of your files.
If the file on the server has **a more recent date** than your local copy, this file won't be mapped.

I deleted the Bootstrap file on the server side and uploaded my local copy, which has an older last modified date. Google Chrome instantly mapped the file to my local workspace.
Out of curiosity I ran `touch bootstrap.min.js` on my server to set the last modified date to today. This broke my file mapping again.

Comment: This was a huge help.

Comment: This is great, except the server I'm working with either has its time misconfigured or something is wrong with timezones.

Answer (score 7):

Chrome removed manually mapping to filesystem resources because of the new Workspaces 2.0 (See: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/10/devtools-release-notes).

You *should* be able to drag and drop your folder into the sources tab and it'll link the files automagically.

However [automatic mapping doesn't work in many situations and there is a Chrome bug to re-add manual mapping](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=809731&q=workspace&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Comment: There is essentially no documentation on how to get it to work if the "magic" drag and drop doesn't work. My local directory is a direct copy of the remote directory. I have added it via drag and drop and yet it just greys it out and doesn't give me any check marks. Previously, we could at least manually line up individual files. Now we can't even do that if the "magic" fizzles.

Comment: There is no way to manually add at the moment. That is why there is no documentation to make it work if drag and drop doesn't work. It looks like you're encountering an existing bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=809731&q=workspace&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem so I downgraded to Chrome 62 (preferences, history, extensions and so on are preserved).

1. Download Chrome 62 from
   https://www.slimjet.com/chrome/google-chrome-old-version.php .
2. On OS X trash /Applications/Google Chrome.
3. Switch off auto-update by setting "defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent alwaysPromptForUpdates 1". Default is 0.
4. May be you have to set "defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent checkInterval 0" too. Default is 18000.
5. Install Chrome 62 as usual.

After starting Chrome 62 open "About Google Chrome". Chrome is checking for updates, but will prompt you to confirm.

[image]

Comment: So what is this site slimjet dot com and why should I trust downloading something from there?

Comment: I can not give any safety guarantee. Google for slimjet.

Comment: how do you settings in step 2 and 3?

Comment: Open Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app. Paste "defaults write com.google.Keystone.Agent alwaysPromptForUpdates 1" (only what is inside the double quotes) in the window and hit Enter.

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem turned out to be the presence of the copyright symbol © in the file headers (which affected just about every file).  With this character in the files, devtool refused to map the files but with it removed, the files map fine.

Comment: I had the same problem with a special char! (for me it was an accent "é"). Thank you!

Comment: It seems to happen with any unicode character in the file. This regex is handy for finding the chars it doesn't like: [^\x00-\x7f]

Comment: A ticket for this problem has been open for over a year: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=972427.  Doesn't seem to be a high priority.

Answer (score 2):

The "Map to File System Resource..." menu item is missing. There appears to be no way to map files. It is completely broken as far as I can tell.

Comment: Damn Chrome , break the important feature without asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also using Chrome 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit) and as I wanted to use the DevTools Live-edit to edit some js files I saw that the option "Map to file system resource" is missing.

After some research I have found out that the Live-edit is perfectly working in Version 63, you just have to:

1. go to Sources and then FileSystem
2. add the folder with your code to the workspace

After that, a small little green point will be displayed near your files (it means the synchronization is ready) and the changes via DevTools can be persisted locally:

[image: Live-edit]

Comment: All of my folders are grayed out, none of my files have the green dot, and there is zero synchronization with the CSS that appears in my browser. What should I do? Also, what does your Network tab look like in that scrripts? Is "scripts" a folder in the root directory?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to others in this thread saying chrome is checking the modified date.

**Adding this to .htaccess solved it for me**

```
IndexOptions SuppressLastModified
```

Of course you would not want this to get into your production code as it could stop browser caching working.

Answer (score 1):

I cleared the cache and it works now.

Previously, I opened my CSS file from my FTP client, then I dragged the containing folder into the Sources tab > Filesystem tab (without caring about any folder names nor structure, I just dragged the FTP clients containing folder into it).

The persistent mapping worked straight away, edits from the Chrome Dev Tools were saving on the server. After 30 minutes of fiddling and playing around, it just stopped working and the CSS resource got greyed out. The file icon with the green dot was not appearing anymore.

[image: not working]

It didn't matter what I'd do, it would not work, but when I cleared my cache, it started to work again.

[image]
[image: persistent mapping]

Answer (score 1):

File mapping started working reliably for me once I turned on a devtools setting -- click the upper-right gear icon and check Preferences > Network > "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"

Answer (score 0):

As of today, with Chrome Version 63.0.3239.108 (Official Build) (64-bit):

The feature appears to be still broken, not working 'automagically' nor consistently with the previous behavior.

However, adding a folder that reflects the resource's URL as seen in the Network tab, make it work again. So if for instance, in the Network Navigator tab you have:

`http://mylocal.site/wp-content/themes/mytheme/assets/sass/partials/_header.scss`

You will just need to add the whole `wp-content/` folder to the Filesystem tab to get the feature work again as expected.

Comment: What if the resource is on a completely different site? Loading `http://mylocal.site.com` and the css file I'm trying to map is on `http://mylocalstaticfiles.site/xxxxxx.css`, for example? This is the use case I'm currently trying to make work, map a css file located on `b.thumbs.redditmedia.com/xxx.css`  (no subdirs) to a site located on reddit.com/r/xxx

Comment: Chrome Canary, in spite of being at Version 65.0.3311.0 , shows the same bug. So I guess your only option at the moment would be trying to recreate locally the same folder structure/file naming as found on the remote site.

Comment: This method isn't working in my case. I have `mysite.com/themes/{themename}/`. On my local system, I have `/home/user/themes/{themename}/`. Regardless of whether I add the {themename} folder or the entire themes folder, the resources refuse to map. Even using the `touch file.css` method mentioned by @Physikbuddha fails to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, but when my source maps included sourcesContent, the file mappings were automatically made and I could live edit my scss. Apparently chrome uses the content to find the right file.

node-sass --source-map-contents