# Angular5 Debugging Not Working in Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript, source-maps, google-developer-tools

I don't know why it doesn't work anymore. I used to be able to open developer tools, place a breakpoint in my angular code, then it would pause. But recently, it's failing to recognize how to map the network files to my local files. Please see my video explanation [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=roAPxWShFVg) (3 minutes long).

Edit:

Some more details: The problem is that when an error is thrown and is logged in the console log, and I click on the line number so chrome developer tools can take me to exactly where the error was thrown, it takes me to the network file which **isn't being mapped to my local file** that I'm editing. It's treating them like they're not related. For this reason, if I put a debug point in the network file, it breaks fine. If I put a debug point in the local file, it doesn't break. How do I tell Chrome how to establish the mapping? It's like they removed this feature.

Comment: I think that I speak for most here when I state that I will not be watching this (or really any) video. Please update the question with the necessary details and include a screen shot (or 2) if necessary. See [mcve] as well as [ask] a good question.

Comment: @Igor it was really complicated and I didn't know hot to elaborate except through a video. Regardless, I put more information.

Comment: Why are you not using separate editor instead of modifying the files in the browser? Try adding `debugger;` in the code and then reload the page to see if it breaks.

Comment: @ManojChalode, because almost all the features I want to use is available in chrome dev tools, and it makes debugging a lot easier. I tried adding `debugger;`. It paused the code on the network version of the file but not the local version. I think I found the problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48032249/chromes-map-to-file-system-resource-not-working-after-update/48097798#48097798

Comment: Did the linked answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me in angular 9. In angular.json file there was a property "optimization" which was set to true and for some reason it was creating optimized files without debugger. I set it to false `"optimization": false`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue.  For me, having active chrome overrides on any files (even for sites different than the one I was debugging) appears to have been screwing with source mapping and rendering me unable to debug my application.  Deleting all of my overrides restored normal debugging functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Works with:

```
    // Use o IntelliSense para saber mais sobre os atributos possíveis.
    // Focalizar para exibir as descrições dos atributos existentes.
    // Para obter mais informações, acesse: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:4200/",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/"
       
        }
    ]
```